# CheckStyle EmptyBlock rule doesn't work

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

I am using `CheckStyle` and the rule for `EmptyBlock` seems to be not working. 
I got an empty `else if{//ignore}` block and based on the documentation the following rule should work but it is not.

```
<module name="EmptyBlock">
      <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_DEFAULT"/>
</module>
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>   <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_DEFAULT"/>
> ```

You are disabling `if` blocks by specifying the `LITERAL_DEFAULT` with no other tokens. `LITERAL_IF` is an optional token as defined in the `Properties` section at http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_blocks.html#EmptyBlock . When you specify a list of tokens, you are disabling all other optional tokens you don't write in.

Use something like `<property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_DEFAULT"/>` to produce a violation on `if (condition) {}`.

Comment: This is still showing me the same error. Must have at least one statement.

Comment: Looks like, it worked. I had this module configured in a wrong file. Thanks rveach.